# One of the operands in the illustration is not permitted

Tags: editor, adobe, adobe-illustrator

some background: i was drawing one file in Adobe illustrator CS6. At the end i saved the file in two formats .ai and .eps. The next day, trying to open the file, I get a message: 
`Can not open the illustration. One of the operands in the illustration is not permitted. Bd (...) 05 Bd.`

For the record, the file can be seen/opened by all the graphic editors, except vector editors.

what i tried: opened the file in Corel - did not help, Corel just crashes. Opened it in Acrobat and save as .eps - it worked, but the picture is a single-layer, that does not suit me. Opened also through the notepad and tried to find a mistake, even though i knew it was unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following for such occasion:
Open a new doc in illustrator ignoring the error message that appears. Place your damaged file into the new document. Select the file that is placed and choose Object Flatten Transparency. Leave all of the defaults. Then remove the clipping mask on the flattened object by clicking shift 7. You should then be able to click into the group, or simply ungroup to get at your design.
All the layers must be saved. The only minus is that the workspace looks like created in a later version.

If this tip doesn't help, then i really don't know how else to handle it. Read other discussions that are related with the problem, here or maybe on adobe forum, msdn, tech and other good ones. This might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e5f9e83-c71f-4339-9020-801b20152dab/corrupted-illustrator-filecant-save?forum=visiogeneral

At any rate, you're lucky that you have two copies and not only .eps. More chances to retrieve the original illustration back.